# Error when creating new android project in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

When I created new android project in my visual studio 2012, this error came out. I already re installed my xamarin.android but still I'am getting this error. How could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you installed the Android support for VS2012? During installation you can choose VS2010 and VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem I just uninstalled the xamarin.android and visual studio 2012 then reinstalled it